# DataTables tables appear incorrectly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatable, twitter-bootstrap-4

I am using **Bootstrap 4** and I followed the example provided by DataTables on this page: [link](https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap4.html).

The code that I used is here: [link](http://pastebin.com/HxSNUnLq)

And here is how it appears:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I tried making the datatables work and I found the issue, you are using a bootstrap css link that conflicts with the one of bootstrap, use these 2 links instead to make the table work.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css"/>
```

Comment: Your links refer to Bootstrap 3 while I'm using 4.

Comment: Okay i see but its the twitter bootstrap that breaking it. If you remove that one the datatable is doing fine

Comment: @ammarx if you add a style attribute to the table "display: inline-block;" is kinda fixed

Comment: But the example on their website works, and Bootstrap 4 is used?